# Is it best practices to increment my MAJOR version number in Maven if I change my dependency list?

Tags: java, maven, semantic-versioning

Suppose I have a web-app and two jars.  The web-app depends on A.jar and that depends on B.jar

If I make A.jar depend on C.jar should A.jar now be a 2.0 release?  If the web-app author doesn't use Maven, updating A.jar without adding C.jar to the project will break his code.

Or conversely if I remove the dependency on A.jar has on B.jar will that be a MAJOR release as well?  If the author was using B.jar transitively and failed to explicitly declare the dependency in his pom.xml, then the disappearance of transitive B.jar with the A.jar update will break his program.

Comment: if you break backward compatibility, then yes > change major version.

Answer (score 1):

> If I make A.jar depend on C.jar should A.jar now be a 2.0 release?

Transitive dependencies in environments that do not support side-by-side package versions cause particularly brittle and vexing inter-product dependency problems for system administrators and product support staff.  If the new C.jar is a major (breaking) update under the [semver rules (#8)](https://semver.org/#spec-item-8), then you must bump the major version number of A.jar.  If it's a minor or patch change in C.jar, then A.jar should receive at least the same level bump, more if A.jar also contains higher level changes than C.jar.

> Or conversely if I remove the dependency on A.jar has on B.jar will that be a MAJOR release as well?

Not if there are no breaking changes in the A.jar customer facing interface. Care should be taken that you do not remove B.jar from a system that has other products dependent on B.jar however.